Vercel alternative to host a large next.js site
I'm searching for a Vercel alternative to host my music site, BeatDetect. It has millions of pages, and Vercel's new pricing, including bot traffic, is driving up costs significantly. The site is still growing and doesn't have much traffic yet, but the costs are becoming unsustainable.
Any recommendations for hosting with good caching for a site with lots of pages would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I have tried only vercel so far. Looking for an alternative

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
